# CSS: visually separate strict markup

Tags: css, css-float

I have HTML markup like this:

```
<div class="top"> </div>
<div class="bottom"> </div>

<div class="top"> </div>
<div class="bottom"> </div>

<div class="top"> </div>
<div class="bottom"> </div>

...
```

How can I move trough CSS all `top` DIVs at the top of the `bottom` DIVs, like this:

```
 top | top | top
 ----------------
 bottom
 ----------------
 bottom
 ----------------
 bottom
```

?

Both type of DIVs should have variable height. And the `top` DIVs should also have variable width.

Comment: Why would you want to do this over just putting all the `top` divs at the top of the HTML?  Layout is good HTML, not just CSS.

Comment: because the code above is for a javascript slider, which shows a active `top` div + one of the `bottom` (content) divs. If the visitor has javascript disabled, I want to display all divs, but in the proper order (title + content)

Comment: If it's for JS, then why not feed it directly into JS and let JS do the layout. CSS really isn't meant to do something like this, so forcing it will give you a hard time making is cross-browser compatible.

Comment: Then you'll have to go the absolute positioning route.  Less than 4% of users have js disabled (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/121108/how-many-people-disable-javascript). similar numbers still use IE6.  Pick your poison carefully.

Comment: Battle's solution works too.  You could physically move the DOM nodes with JS to make the CSS cleaner for the JS enabled layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No way to do it without absolute positioning.  Plus if i might say there is no reason what so ever for you to go about it this way.  There has to be a better more intuative way.